# How do I apply a css style to a template in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

```
<template name="userPill">
    <span>{{Zipcode}}</span>
    <span>{{City}}</span>
</template>
```

The above template is being used for a meteor autocomplete. What I need is a vertical scrollbar  on a container that is around the list, so a user can scroll through these values. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `template` tag does not exist in the DOM, so you can't rely on it for CSS. If you need to target that template specifically (as opposed to adding generic classes to its elements), your best bet is to wrap its contents in a div like so:

```html
<template name="userPill">
  <div class="user-pill">
    <span>{{Zipcode}}</span>
    <span>{{City}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then you can target it in your css:

```css
.user-pill {
  color: red;
}
```

In larger projects, I prefer to use a double underscore to identify class names for templates, e.g. `<div class="__user-pill">`. It may look a little ugly but I find it's really helpful to figure out what's going on.

---

Based on your comment, it looks like you need to style the container of a `userPill`. Let's say you have a template like this:

```html
<template name="userPillContainer">
  <div class="user-pill-container">
    {{> userPill name="home"}}
    {{> userPill name="about"}}
    {{> userPill name="profile"}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Then you can target the container in the same way as above:

```css
.user-pill-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I did that but then this style is applied to every item in the list. What I need is to apply the style to the container which around it.